# R create a yearly dataframe with quarterly data

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this one :

```
date    value
"2010Q1"  1.200
"2010Q2"  1.203
"2010Q3"  2.111
"2010Q4"  2.165
"2011Q1"  1.455
"2011Q2"  1.356
"2011Q3"  2.056
"2011Q4"  2.134
```

I would like to sum each quarter of a given year in order to have the total value of the year.
I am looking for a function returning :

```
date   value 
2010   6679
2011   7001
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Remove Quarter information from `date` and then sum by group - `aggregate(value~date, transform(df, date = sub('Q\\d$', '', date)), sum)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Answer (score 0):

You could take the first 4 letters of the `date` column, and then aggregate:

```
dat[,"year"] <- substr(dat[,"date"], 1, 4))
aggregate(value ~ year, data=dat, FUN=sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `dplyr` and then `tsibble` and `lubridate` to get the quarter format and year format. But you can do it by just subtracting the year string as well.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~date   , ~value,
  "2010Q1",  1.200,
  "2010Q2",  1.203,
  "2010Q3",  2.111,
  "2010Q4",  2.165,
  "2011Q1",  1.455,
  "2011Q2",  1.356,
  "2011Q3",  2.056,
  "2011Q4",  2.134
)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(yearquarter = yearquarter(date),
         year = year(yearquarter))

df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(sum_value = sum(value))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>    year sum_value
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1  2010      6.68
#> 2  2011      7.00
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>